# Upgrade Net Framework 4.7.1 to Net 6 makes WCF service consumption slower

Tags: asp.net, performance, asp.net-core, wcf

We are rewriting our .Net Framework 4.7.1 backend to .Net 6 and we have a first version. But when performing performance test in local we observed that with same configuration the queries are slower with the new backend. This occurs when consuming data from WCF service : before it took average 200 ms, now it is 650 ms

We had the connected services configured in our web.config

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
  <diagnostics performanceCounters="Off">
    <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"/>
  </diagnostics>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="DocumentSecuredServiceBinding" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" textEncoding="utf-8" messageEncoding="Mtom" maxReceivedMessageSize="209715200" maxBufferPoolSize="5242880" maxBufferSize="209715200">
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint name="DocumentServiceImpl" address="https://service/DocumentSecuredService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DocumentSecuredServiceBinding" behaviorConfiguration="CredentialIdentificationBehavior" contract="DocumentService.DocumentSecuredService"/>
  </client>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="CredentialIdentificationBehavior">
        <clientCredentials>
          <clientCertificate findValue="CertName" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My"/>
        </clientCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Now configuration is loaded from appsettings.json in an abstract factory and its implementation :

```cs
public abstract class BaseSecuredServiceFactory
{
    protected readonly X509Certificate2 _clientCertificate;

    protected readonly Binding _binding;

    protected readonly EndpointAddress _endpointAdress;

    protected BaseSecuredServiceFactory(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, EndpointOptions option)
    {
        _clientCertificate = LoadCertificate(option.CertificateSubjectName);

        _binding = new BasicHttpBinding()
        {
            BypassProxyOnLocal = option.ByPassProxyOnLocal,
            ReceiveTimeout = option.ReceiveTimeout,
            SendTimeout = option.SendTimeout,
            TextEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            MessageEncoding = option.MessageEncoding,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = option.MaxReceivedMessageSize,
            MaxBufferPoolSize = option.MaxBufferPoolSize,
            MaxBufferSize = option.MaxBufferSize,
            TransferMode = option.TransferMode,
            Security = new BasicHttpSecurity()
            {
                Mode = option.SecurityMode,
                Transport = new HttpTransportSecurity()
                {
                    ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate
                }
            }
        };

        _endpointAdress = new EndpointAddress(option.EndpointAdress);
    }

    protected static X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate(string subjectName)
    {
        // Load certificate from store My of LocalMachine
        X509Store store = new(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        X509Certificate2Collection certificates = store.Certificates.Find(
            X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
            subjectName,
            false
        );
        if (certificates.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                $"The certificate with subject name '{subjectName}' could not be found."
            );
        }

        return certificates[0];
    }
}
```

```cs
public class DocumentSecuredServiceFactory
    : BaseSecuredServiceFactory,
        IDocumentSecuredServiceFactory
{
    public DocumentSecuredServiceFactory(
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        IOptions<DocumentEndpointOptions> options
    )
        : base(loggerFactory, options.Value) { }

    public DocumentSecuredServiceClient GetDocumentSecuredService()
    {
        DocumentSecuredServiceClient result = new(_binding, _endpointAdress);
        result.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new InspectorBehavior(_loggerFactory));
        result.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = _clientCertificate;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Configuration section in appsettings.json

```json
// Document Secured Service configuration
{
  "ByPassProxyOnLocal": false,
  "ReceiveTimeout": "00:10:00",
  "SendTimeout": "00:10:00",
  "MessageEncoding": "Mtom",
  "MaxReceivedMessageSize": 209715200,
  "MaxBufferPoolSize": 5242880,
  "MaxBufferSize": 209715200,
  "TransferMode": 0, // Buffered
  "SecurityMode": 1,
  "HttpClientCredentialType": 5,
  "EndpointAdress": "https://service/DocumentSecuredService",
  "CertificateSubjectName": "CertName"
}
```

Here is ConnectedService.json generated in Net 6 from a local wsdl file

```
{
  "ExtendedData": {
    "inputs": [
      "../wsdl/DocumentSecuredServiceV002.wsdl"
    ],
    "collectionTypes": [
      "System.Array",
      "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2"
    ],
    "namespaceMappings": [
      "*, BslDocumentService"
    ],
    "references": [
      "AutoMapper, {AutoMapper, 12.0.0}",
      "C:\\Source\\TIPI\\Tipi Backend\\Tipi.Backend.Web\\Tipi.Backend.Web.Services\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0\\Tipi.Backend.Web.Client.Models.dll",
      "C:\\Source\\TIPI\\Tipi Backend\\Tipi.Backend.Web\\Tipi.Backend.Web.Services\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0\\Tipi.Backend.Web.Core.dll",
      "C:\\Source\\TIPI\\Tipi Backend\\Tipi.Backend.Web\\Tipi.Backend.Web.Services\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0\\Tipi.Backend.Web.Data.dll",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal, 6.0.11}",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation, 6.0.11}",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore, 6.0.11}",
      "Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, {Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, 5.0.0}",
      "Microsoft.Data.Sqlite, {Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core, 6.0.11}",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, 6.0.11}",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions, {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions, 6.0.11}",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, 6.0.11}",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite, {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core, 6.0.11}",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions, {Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions, 6.0.0}",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory, {Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory, 6.0.1}",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, {Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, 6.0.0}",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, {Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, 6.0.1}",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, {Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, 6.0.0}",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel, {Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel, 6.0.0}",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core, {Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core, 6.0.11}",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores, {Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores, 6.0.11}",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions, {Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions, 7.0.0}",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, {Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, 6.0.0}",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, {Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, 6.0.0}",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool, {Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool, 5.0.10}",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Options, {Microsoft.Extensions.Options, 6.0.0}",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, {Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, 6.0.0}",
      "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging, {Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging, 6.8.0}",
      "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WsTrust, {Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WsTrust, 6.8.0}",
      "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, {Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, 6.8.0}",
      "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml, {Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml, 6.8.0}",
      "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Xml, {Microsoft.IdentityModel.Xml, 6.8.0}",
      "Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents, {Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents, 7.0.0}",
      "Newtonsoft.Json, {Newtonsoft.Json, 13.0.1}",
      "NLog, {NLog, 5.0.5}",
      "NLog.Extensions.Logging, {NLog.Extensions.Logging, 5.1.0}",
      "NLog.Web.AspNetCore, {NLog.Web.AspNetCore, 5.1.5}",
      "Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore, {Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore, 6.21.90}",
      "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, {Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core, 3.21.90}",
      "SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2, {SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3, 2.0.6}",
      "SQLitePCLRaw.core, {SQLitePCLRaw.core, 2.0.6}",
      "SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3, {SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3, 2.0.6}",
      "System.Collections.Immutable, {System.Collections.Immutable, 6.0.0}",
      "System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, {System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, 6.0.0}",
      "System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, {System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, 6.0.0}",
      "System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter, {System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter, 6.0.0}",
      "System.DirectoryServices, {System.DirectoryServices, 7.0.0}",
      "System.DirectoryServices.Protocols, {System.DirectoryServices.Protocols, 5.0.1}",
      "System.Drawing.Common, {System.Drawing.Common, 7.0.0}",
      "System.Formats.Asn1, {System.Formats.Asn1, 6.0.0}",
      "System.IO, {System.IO, 4.3.0}",
      "System.Reflection.DispatchProxy, {System.Reflection.DispatchProxy, 4.7.1}",
      "System.Runtime, {System.Runtime, 4.3.0}",
      "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, {System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, 6.0.0}",
      "System.Security.AccessControl, {System.Security.AccessControl, 6.0.0}",
      "System.Security.Cryptography.Cng, {System.Security.Cryptography.Cng, 4.5.0}",
      "System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs, {System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs, 6.0.1}",
      "System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData, {System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData, 6.0.0}",
      "System.Security.Cryptography.Xml, {System.Security.Cryptography.Xml, 6.0.1}",
      "System.Security.Permissions, {System.Security.Permissions, 7.0.0}",
      "System.Security.Principal.Windows, {System.Security.Principal.Windows, 5.0.0}",
      "System.ServiceModel, {System.ServiceModel.Primitives, 4.10.2}",
      "System.ServiceModel.Duplex, {System.ServiceModel.Duplex, 4.10.2}",
      "System.ServiceModel.Federation, {System.ServiceModel.Federation, 4.10.2}",
      "System.ServiceModel.Http, {System.ServiceModel.Http, 4.10.2}",
      "System.ServiceModel.NetTcp, {System.ServiceModel.NetTcp, 4.10.2}",
      "System.ServiceModel.Primitives, {System.ServiceModel.Primitives, 4.10.2}",
      "System.ServiceModel.Security, {System.ServiceModel.Security, 4.10.2}",
      "System.Text.Encoding, {System.Text.Encoding, 4.3.0}",
      "System.Text.Encodings.Web, {System.Text.Encodings.Web, 6.0.0}",
      "System.Text.Json, {System.Text.Json, 6.0.0}",
      "System.Threading.Tasks, {System.Threading.Tasks, 4.3.0}",
      "System.Windows.Extensions, {System.Windows.Extensions, 7.0.0}",
      "System.Xml.ReaderWriter, {System.Xml.ReaderWriter, 4.3.0}",
      "System.Xml.XmlDocument, {System.Xml.XmlDocument, 4.3.0}"
    ],
    "sync": true,
    "targetFramework": "net6.0",
    "typeReuseMode": "All"
  }
}
```

I have updated to latest version System.ServiceModel packages (6.0.0). In previous backend it was 4.0.0 version. I have used svcUtil version 2.1.0

I have compared both service object instanciate and i can not see any differences that could explain the slow performances

I have also tried to change few settings and to use other bindings (NetTcpBinding and WSHttpBinding) without success

We work only on client side of WCF service

Thank you in advance for your help

**EDIT**
I have improved new times to 500ms thanks to this change https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/5002

Comment: Recommended to use gRPC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/why-grpc  gRPC Examples: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/tree/master/examples

Comment: Unfortunately we do not manage the server API and it does not support gRPC

Comment: The versions in ConnectetService.json are 4.10.2, not 6.0. Have you tried recreating the proxy/service reference *after* installing the 6.0 packages? The issue you pointed to was closed close to the 6.0 release

Comment: In any case, in 2023 SOAP is legacy technology. .NET Core didn't even have proper support for it at first. The `svcutil` global tool first appear in .NET Core 2.1 and server-side WCF is actually a community project, [CoreWCF](https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF). There's simply not enough interest for SOAP (and hence WCF) so it doesn't get the same resources or community contributions as REST or gRPC. If the server supports a more modern API, consider moving to it. Commercial services are deprecating their SOAP services in favor of REST already

Comment: Yes i have recreated references but still slow performance, Unfortunately the API of our client only support SOAP so we are stuck with it. They will move the API to REST but they do not know when. I guess we will have to stay with .Net Framework until then, or we optimize our algo to compensate the loss of performance

Comment: Try use UltraMapper https://github.com/maurosampietro/UltraMapper to override AutoMapper. UltraMappper more fast.

Comment: @Ihdina we do not want to have dependencies to external github project

Comment: @JoffreyFerreira See the references section in ConnectedService.json, there you use a lot of libraries from github. I don't see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

After creating an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/5184) on WCF team github , two solutions have been proposed :

- Work HttpClientFactory but it would need a lot of modifications on our code
- Add `DocumentSecuredServiceV002Client.CacheSetting = CacheSetting.AlwaysOn;` before first client instance. We did this and performances were faster than our current API